# Tomcat DBCP, Connection closing issue during bulk insertion

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data-jpa, apache-commons-dbcp, tomcat-dbcp

I am using Tomcat connection pool to connect to database. 
In my spring data class I am calling repository.save(List) with around 100 000 records. After executing DB queries for some time,the statement is failing saying connection is already closed. I am not sure what property we need to set to resolve the issue.

I am using oracle database.

Comment: please share stacktrace/logs and code-snippet for more details.

Comment: Besides the full stacktrace, share the definition/configuration of your connection pool